# Durandal framework basics

Tags: javascript, dom-events, durandal

I am going through few slides in developing a SPA using Durandal and other JavaScript library.

I have a few questions:

```
define('projects', [],
    function() {

        
        var Projects = function () {
            this.myDataLocal = ko.observable(); 
            this.myDataFromServices = null;
        };

        Projects.prototype.activate = function (activationData) {
            this.myDataFromServices = activationData
            this.myDataLocal(activationData());
        };
     Projects.prototype.detached = function () {
            this.myDataFromServices(this.myDataLocal());  
        };

        return Projects; 
    }
  );
```

a. In the above code is

```
var Projects = function () {
            
        };
```

a constructor?

b. When we are adding a function to prototype ,

```
Projects.prototype.activate = function (activationData) {
}
```

will this also be considered as a constructor and executed automatically on the function load?

c. To qualify a function for a constructor is it enough if we are defining the name of the just like this?

```
var ProjectsSample100 = function () {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Not exactly no. Although an object 'Projects' is created.

B) This is not a constructor. This assigns a function to a property on the prototype of the Projects object. In particular in Durandal, when a viewmodel is loaded, Durandal will check for the existance of an 'activate' function on the viewmodel. If none is present, it uses a default function, but in this case we have explicitly set the activation behaviour.

See more about what stages a viewmodel goes through in Durandal here:
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

C) No. That is just an object getting defined.

A typical constructor looks like this:

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
```

Notice the use of 'this' to assign to 'fields' on the object, and the use of 'new' to create new instances with this constructor.

I have stolen this example from here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp